# Interface Builder (iPhone dev) custom button background Image does not respect Stretching settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, uikit, interface-builder, uibutton

I'm attempting to create a custom button using a background image in Interface Builder.  The image has stretchable and non-stretchable parts so that it can be resized.

IB exposes the Stretching properties to allow for this, yet no values I put in affect how the button appears.  It is always fully stretched to fill the size of the frame.

Is this this a unsupported feature in IB or in UIButton perhaps?

http://img.skitch.com/20100103-rjabkq2c2jkqynw47crxepdtwb.jpg

(Note: The above stretch values are not the ones that will work with the image properly, but just the values I was messing with at the time of the screenshot)

Comment: Same problem with same sample files from UICatalog. Any progress? Did you have to set it up in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example in *Beginning iPhone 3 Development* only the *UIImage leftCapWidth* and *topCapHeight* are used, and the image is created/set programmatically, so that's an alternate method if contentStretch isn't working.

Comment: Seems this just doesn't work as it might seem it would.  The docs talk about these values doing exactly what I want (the whole button image stretching thing).  Having to programmatically make the button look correct is kind of odd given we have a whole GUI making GUI... aka IB.

Comment: Looking at the docs for contentStretch, the defaults that IB show (particular the 0.50's) are not the actual defaults of h/w 0,0 and size 1,1 so I guess it's not too surprising that the settings in IB don't work. Looks like contentStretch was added in 3.0 so that's probably got something to do with it.  http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: I don't follow.  I'm not using the defaults.  As I said, no values I put in there have any impact.  The ones shown in the screen shot are not the defaults.  I was running under 3.0.

Comment: Got the same problem here. So far always did it in code but was hoping   for it to just work in IB as well ...to save me the code an IBOutlets.

Comment: If any/all of you would like to see this fixed or better documented, please consider filing a bug (or at least duping rdar://7706446). 

http://bugreporter.apple.com/

Comment: I have added sample code of how to get a button with contentStretch'ing background image.

Comment: This short blog entry has an explanation for this apparent failure that seems reasonable: http://www.codebunnygames.com/?p=78

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you want more than one pixel to stretch (ie. a pattern in the center of the button) the stretchable UIImage does not work.

The UIButton's contentStretch does also not work properly.

How I solved it: I subclassed UIButton and added a `UIImageView *backgroundImageView` as property and placed it at index 0 as a subview within the `UIButton`. I then ensure in layoutSubviews that it fits the button entirely and set the highlighted states of the imageView. All you need to do is handover a UIImageView with the correct contentStretch and contentMode applied.

**.h file**

```
@interface ButtonWithBackgroundImage : UIButton {
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
}
@property (retain) UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
+ (ButtonWithBackgroundImage*)button;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
@implementation ButtonWithBackgroundImage
@synthesize backgroundImageView;

+ (ButtonWithBackgroundImage*)button {
return [self buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
}
- (void)setBackgroundImageView:(UIImageView*)img {
    [backgroundImageView removeFromSuperview];
    [backgroundImageView release];

    backgroundImageView = [img retain];

    if(backgroundImageView){
        [self insertSubview:backgroundImageView atIndex:0];
        [self setNeedsLayout];
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)select {
    [super setSelected:select];
    // we subclass the setSelect method to highlight the background imageview
[backgroundImageView setHighlighted:select||self.highlighted];
}
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highl {
    [super setHighlighted:highl];

    // we subclass the setHighlighted method to highlight the background imageview    
    [backgroundImageView setHighlighted:highl||self.selected];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.backgroundImageView.frame = self.bounds;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [backgroundImageView release];
    backgroundImageView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The button's background image will always be resized to fill the frame; the foreground image will not be resized (if there's no text, it is centered). The logic of stretching is that it resizes the middle while leaving the borders intact; for example, for a rounded rectangle this means that the rounded corners will not be distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Xcode Slicing feature to specify the dimensions of a resizable center area of the image and to optionally specify end caps, which are areas of the image that should not be filled by the resizable area.
See [About Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH4-SW1)

Answer (score -1):

I have got it working!!! The magic values for me are 0.2 and 0.2.

My image is a box within a box, both with round corners.

When it is 0.2 and 0.8, it leaves the top of the image unstretched, but the bottom is stretched and distorted.

I guess, the first 0.2 is the offset meaning how much not to stretch, and the 2nd one is probably how much to stretch. At least, 0.2 and 0.6 work too.

In principle, you may make an experiment: take an image of a lattice or concentric circles or a color gradient and stretch it. If you do, please post the image :) .